# Facebook api question

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the facbook's javascript sdk you can post to someone's wall by doing

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {message: 'hello' }, function(response) {});
```

But how can you post pictures, links, etc.  I tried this...

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {picture:'somePicLink', link:'someLink', type:'link' }, function(response) {
});
```

This does not work for parameters such as picture, link and type for the feed graph api, it only seems to work just for message.

Answer (score 1):

That should work. I'm guessing you're error is something small like not using an absolute url for the picture or link.

Change your code to this to see what the error is:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {picture:'somePicLink', link:'someLink', type:'link' },      
    function(response) {
         if(response.error)
              alert(response.error.message);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you cannot do this is because you'll need an access token, as stated in the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).